# pic16f877a RS232 not working

Tags: serial-port, pic

i am trying to make rs232 protocol communcication from my pic to serial port in pc I made sure all myconnections are right by connecting tx and rx of serial port each step I connect them anywhere else so I guess the circuit is ok and here it is:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktJQX.png

this circuit I did connect in real life and just did It in proteus to demonstrate

I just want the pic to send every byte it receives and I set the baud rate and stop, parity bits the same in both. I made the code in mikroc, here it is:

```
char uart_rd;

void main() {

  UART1_Init(9600);               // Initialize UART module at 9600 bps
  Delay_ms(100);                  // Wait for UART module to stabilize

  while (1) {                     // Endless loop
    if (UART1_Data_Ready()) {     // If data is received,
      uart_rd = UART1_Read();     // read the received data,
      UART1_Write(uart_rd);       // and send data via UART
    }
  }
}
```

just this small part. I don't really know where the problem is everything seems right but it is not working I would very much appreciate replies from anyone it would really help me a lot thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the schematic P1 appears to be a DE-9 connector with pin 2 wired as an input and pin 3 as an output. A PC is wired the same way. If P1 is a male connector you must use a null modem cable between your circuit and the PC. A null modem cable has female connectors on both ends with signals crossed over internally.  If P1 is a female connector wire pin 2 as the output and pin 3 as the input and use a male to female cable.